# Confidential data encryption on blockchain

Tags: blockchain, javascript, encryption

I already built a supply chain that is able to collect product information on Ethereum. Now, that data can be confidential, but I still want to do Matrix calculations on it. I came across homomorphic encryption, but I'm not sure if it would help me. My product information has a JSON format like that:

```
{  
"Timestamp": UNIX,  
"Materials": [  
{  
 "Chemical1": XXXX mol,  
 "Chemical2": XXXX mol,  
}  
],      
"CO2": XXX kg,  
"Energy": XXX kWh,  
"Water": XXX m²,  
"Price": XXX €,  
"Amount": XXX,  
"Totalprice": Price * Amount   
}
```

I want to be able to extract the specific information I want from that file and calculate with it but it also has to be confidential/encrypted. Does someone have an idea which method would be the best to do that and is there maybe a JavaScript package for that?

Thank you

Max